# PHP - Give Error on Convert a 12Hour Format Time to a new timezone

Tags: php, time, timezone

I get the Error **sometime** on Converting 12hour format time from a Timezone to new 
TimeZone

***Error:***

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (00:00:31 AM) at position 9 (A): The timezone could not be found in the database' in C:\xampp\php\udp.php:105
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\php\udp.php(105): DateTime->__construct('00:00:31 AM', Object(DateTimeZone))
#1 {main}  thrown in C:\xampp\php\udp.php on line 105
```

***MyCodes:***

```
// $gps_time = "9:43:52"; 
$gps_time      = $time_hour.":".$time_min.":".$time_sec;
// $time_received = "01:45:04 2012-07-28"; 
$time_received = date('H:i:s Y-m-d');

$utc = new DateTimeZone("UTC"); 
$moscow = new DateTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"); 

//Instantiate both AM and PM versions of your time 
$gps_time_am = new DateTime("$gps_time AM", $utc); 
$gps_time_pm = new DateTime("$gps_time PM", $utc); 

//Received time 
$time_received = new DateTime($time_received, $moscow); 

//Change timezone to Moscow 
$gps_time_am->setTimezone($moscow); 
$gps_time_pm->setTimezone($moscow); 

//Check the difference in hours. If it's less than 1 hour difference, it's the correct one. 
if ($time_received->diff($gps_time_pm)->h < 1) { 

$correct_time = $gps_time_pm->format("H:i:s Y-m-d");
} 
else { 

$correct_time = $gps_time_am->format("H:i:s Y-m-d");
}

echo $correct_time;
```

***Question:*** Where's the problem !!?
P.S: above Code is a part of my udp socket and run from php cli

Comment: 10:39:6 AM is the problem, it should be 10:39:06 AM.

Comment: @qxxx i'ts Should be Fix , Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Summary

Put simply, that PHP is trying (mistakenly, for your needs) to read `AM` as a timezone and `AM` is not a valid timezone.

---

### Details

`10:39:6 AM` gets separated into the following pieces

- `10:39:6` it recognises as `timelong24` (a 24-hour formatted time with seconds)
- `AM` it recognises as `tz` (timezone).

In contrast, for `10:39:06 AM` it correctly parses the whole string as `timelong12` (a 12-hour formatted time with seconds and AM/PM).

### Boring bit

The reason for this strange behaviour lies in the date parsing logic ([source](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/date/lib/parse_date.re)).  The relevant patterns are:

**timelong24**

```
't'?
[01]?[0-9] | "2"[0-4]              # hour24
[:.]
[0-5]?[0-9]                        # minute
[:.]
[0-5]?[0-9] | "60"                 # second;
```

**timelong12**

```
"0"?[1-9] | "1"[0-2]               # hour12
[:.]
[0-5]?[0-9]                        # minute
[:.]
[0-5][0-9] | "60"                  # secondlz
[ \t]*                             # space?
([AaPp] "."? [Mm] "."?) [\000\t ]  # meridian;
```

As you can see, to match the `timelong12` format (which is what we really wanted), the *seconds* portion of the time *must* be double-digits.